# Finding lowest number in a string in PHP

Tags: php

Given a string such as

> $50.78 now only $15.36

I need to be able to extract and store the lowest number found in that string. The first thing I did was use `str_replace` to remove the dollar signs, but I am stuck from there. Any suggestions?

Comment: explode what you get after getting rid of the dollar sign, by the white space, so you should write this `explode(" ",$stringwithoutdollar);` , and then you'll get an array, loop through it, and compare the numbers that you got in there, and take the minimum of them.. Hop you understand

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` to get an array of all the numbers, sort the array, and take the first number.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: extract numbers into an array, sort array, pick off last/first value, as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are your friend, friend!

```
$str = "$50.78 now only $15.36";
$prices = array();

// Make the prices variable available to anonymous functions
global $prices;

preg_replace_callback("/^\$([0-9\.]+) now only \$([0-9\.]+)$/i", function($m)
{
    global $prices;
    $prices[] = $m[1];
    $prices[] = $m[2];
}, $str);
```

Now you have an array `$prices` that you can simply sort using `sort($prices)` to get the lowest price (at index 0).

Comment: Regular expressions are the way to go haha, thanks!